# How to set rpath or runpath larger then it was originally?

Tags: elf, rpath

I have stumbled on a problem: I need to change the `rpath`, but I need it larger than it originally was.

`chrpath` won't rewrite the whole file, so it allows only narrowing. How do I enlarge that space? Is there another re-compiler to set a larger `rpath`/`runpath`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) -- it has no limitations on the length of the new path.

Comment: patchelf has many issues right? recently I tried to use it but there is one issue after another

Comment: @widesense I haven't seen any issues with `patchelf`, but I am sure there could be some. If you have an MCVE, you can ask here or report in the `patchelf` bug tracker.